# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Class at table: table1, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(end_table2)]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I know this kind of questions has been posted before. But I tried all the solutions online and none of them fixed my problem. I work on *Spring-MVC* project, in the business logic layer I define several entities to be mapped to the database. I have set up a many to many relationship between 2 classes: `Monument` and `Circuit`. But I get this *error*:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.entities.Monument, at table: circuit, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(end_monument)]
```

This is my first class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "monument")
public class Monument {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private double latitude;

    @Column(name = "longtitude")
    private double longtitude;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "foundation_date")
    private Date foundationDate;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
                    CascadeType.DETACH,
                    CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "circuit_monument",
                    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "monument_id"),
                    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "circuit_id"))
    private List<Circuit> circuits;

    // constructors & getters é setters

}
```

And my second class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "circuit")
public class Circuit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "start_monument")
    private Monument start;

    @Column(name = "end_monument")
    private Monument end;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
                    CascadeType.DETACH,
                    CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "circuit_monument",
                    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "circuit_id"),
                    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "monument_id"))
    private List<Monument> monuments;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "circuit_id")
    private List<Comment> comments;

    // constructors & getters & setters
}
```

And here is the exceptions stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'touristController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'touristService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'touristServiceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'touristDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'touristDaoImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.configuration.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.entities.Monument, at table: circuit, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(end_monument)]
```

Comment: You miss the @OneToOne annotation

Comment: Why would I use @OneToOne annotation ? I don't understand what you are referring to.

Comment: It is a reference to an other entity.

Comment: What @Jens is trying to tell you is that you need to mark `Circuit.start` and `Circuit.end` with either `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne`, because those are associations to another entity rather than simple columns. You'll also want to use `@JoinColumn` rather than `@Column` for those fields

Comment: Yes exactly, I figuered it out. It was a silly mistake from my part. Thanks Jens for the answer and thanks @crizzis for clarifying the answer.